# Codeigniter get and display post from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I updated my website recently but I have a lot of old data in the database that I want to show in the archive. I'm not an expert on Codeigniter. So if possible please explain me the details as much can. My current website is built using Codeigniter.

**My Database Table**

1. old_archive (id, title, slug, category_id_one, category_id_two, body)
2. cat_one ( id, category_name, slug)
3. cat_two ( id, category_name, slug)

I want to show data like this structured URL.

> www.example.com/(if cat_one is not empty->category_name)/(if cat_two
>   is not empty->category_name)/id-slug.html

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your controller

```
public function Get_allcat(){
$this->load->model('model-name');
$cat_one = $this->model-name->Get_CatOne(); //it will give an array in return. if you want to handle one by one then use foreach loop as well
$cat_two = $this->model-name->Get_CatTwo(); //if you want to get specific category_name in return then pass some parameter to model function for where condition in database 
$old_archive = $this->model-name->Get_Old_Archive();
if(!empty($cat_one))
{
   if(!empty($cat_two))
   {
     if(!empty($old_archive))
     {
       redirect('www.example.com/'.$cat_one.'/'.$cat_two.'/'.$old_archive['id'].'/'.$old_archive['slug'].'.html');
}
  }  
     }
```

In your model

```
public function Get_CatOne(){
$this->db->select("category_name");
$this->db->from("cat_one");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
}

public function Get_CatTwo(){
$this->db->select("category_name");
$this->db->from("cat_two");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
}

public function Get_Old_Archive(){
$this->db->select("id, slug");
$this->db->from("old_archive");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but actually, what I want it's not fulfilling... url will be like this --> www.example.com/computer/accessories/1234-pen-drive-64gb.html | here computer is > cat_one & accessories is > cat_two & 1234 is old_archive 'id' & pen-drive-64gb is old_archive slug,

Comment: So you want to use your URL against a particular row?

Comment: I don't understand! can you please give me the solution that I mention in the last comment.

Comment: Mr. Alex, I already mention I have data in the database. I asked for the solution, not negative marking. If you can't give solution then can ask for more details right?

Comment: @HASNAT  See my updated answer. It's only for one row. If you want to get specific category's detail (e.g. computer, laptop, mobile) use a dropdown it will help you and will make your scenario more easy